# System.InvalidOperationException: Namespace prefix 'xsd' is not defined on surface pro

Tags: workflow, infopath

I have an InfoPath form that has a people picker, and a Workflow that sets permissions on the item. Once the form is saved, an error occurs on the workflow and looking into the logs there is this error

> System.InvalidOperationException: Namespace prefix 'xsd' is not
>   defined.

This error also only happens when using a surface pro and works fine when using a computer. Any ideas of what I can look at?

Comment: Did you got it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Surface Pro is using `IE Edge` or `IE11` that is for sure.

So by the given error, I can say that you might be using custom master page for your SharePoint Site & there is an issue with the people picker compatibility with some IE browsers.

There are so many issues with using IE. So You have had to change back the

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>`

to

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>`

in the master pages, and have lost all the nice looking CSS and HTML when you look at our SharePoint sits with IE.

You can find the more explanation at below mentioned link.

['Namespace prefix 'xsd' is not defined' error in people picker when using IE9, IE10, IE11](https://helpcenter.elearningforce.com/hc/en-us/articles/202050911--Namespace-prefix-xsd-is-not-defined-error-in-people-picker-when-using-IE9-IE10-IE11)